# How to query Docker nameservers?

Tags: webserver, dig

When I try to update my Ubuntu 18.04,I encounter problems

```
Err:13 https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker InRelease                                                                                            
  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.204.15.85 443]
```

I was looking around and start using dig to query the docker namervers. Anyway with info I get I do not have a clue how to fix my problem.

```
dig @8.8.8.8  get.docker.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.7-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 get.docker.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 4347
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;get.docker.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
get.docker.com.     119 IN  CNAME   d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net.
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   143.204.214.94
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   143.204.214.26
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   143.204.214.20
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   143.204.214.98

;; Query time: 97 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 19 07:06:39 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 150
```

But only docker.com gives different output

```
 dig @8.8.8.8  docker.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.7-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 docker.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 57084
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;docker.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
docker.com.     59  IN  A   52.86.8.163
docker.com.     59  IN  A   52.205.36.130
docker.com.     59  IN  A   3.217.62.246

;; Query time: 62 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 19 07:06:42 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 87
```

And docs.dockers.com

```
dig @8.8.8.8 docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.7-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 3301
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86393   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019061900 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 42 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 19 07:15:40 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 151
```

What should I do now? How to interpret dig output?

Comment: What where you trying to do when you got the error? Update the docker code on your system, or update an Ubuntu-based container image or something else? And what makes you think the "Forbidden" comes for a DNS problem?

Comment: sudo apt update.

Comment: If it is not DNS problem,what is it? I am trying to find out,please give some suggestions.

Comment: "403 Forbidden" implies that you reached some HTTP/HTTPS server, but that it didn't let you retrieve things from it. So DNS resolution occurs. OTOH this looks like your APT thinks that `get.docker.com` is a place to get Debian packages and it doesn't look so. The only resource on get.docker.com is a script to run on your system to install docker. So are you using it correctly?